# Java constructor, illegal expression

Tags: java

So I get the `Illegal start of expression` error in this constructor:

```
public V10String()
{
  this.left = left;
  this.val=val;
  this.right=right;
  this.height=height;
}
```

which appears to disappear when I remove the `public`. But then the `left`,`right`, etc. are not recognized. This was exactly as my professor had it AFAIK. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member should be declared outside the constructor :

```
public class V10String
{
    public int height;
    public String val;
    public AVLTreeNode left,right;

    public V10String() // this constructor assign default values to the members
    {
        this.height = 0;
        this.val    = null;
        this.left   = null;
        this.right  = null;    
    }

    // this constructor assigns to the members values passed to it by the caller
    public V10String(int height, String val, AVLTreeNode left, AVLTreeNode right) 
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.val    = val;
        this.left   = left;
        this.right  = right;
    }
}
```

Variables declared inside the constructor (or any other method) are local variable, and have no access modifiers (since they can only be accessed by the method/constructor in which they are declared).

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the reply. What does the constructor contain?

Comment: @Firkamon The constructor may contain initialization of the members of the class.

Comment: @Firkamon: Logic, rather than declaration.

Comment: @Firkamon Almost. You forgot to add arguments to your constructor. For example, if you don't add an argument called `left`, the line `this.left = left` is the same as `this.left = this.left`, which is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Eran's answer is right but I guess you want to do something like,

You also need to pass the parameters in constructor.

```
public int height;
public String val;
public AVLTreeNode left,right;

public V10String(int height, String val, AVLTreeNode left, AVLTreeNode right)
{
    this.height = height;
    this.val =  val;
    this.left =  left;
    this.right = right;
}
```